# Get Product listing page filtered only by manufacture attribute with layered navigation

Tags: product-list

I m trying to list all the products of a same manufacture on a page from different categories on click of manufacture name with layered navigation,help me out with solution i have tried with advance search but couldn't get layered navigation on that page

i can get collection by

> $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
>           ->getCollection()
>           ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturer_id);

how do i pass this in list.php or should i make new custom module so that i can get layered navigation on that page

Comment: I've seen this question asked dozens of times.  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503447/magento-how-to-add-layered-navigation-to-advanced-search

Comment: @seanbreeden i have been to that thread but i need to know is there workaround to that can i pass custom collection to list.phtml when i click on brand item